# How to deploy ActiveX dll from web page

Tags: dll, setup-project, cab, activexobject, regasm

Been trying off and on for days now and can't figure this out. I have written a C# class file for an Intranet app to control the local serial ports. It works great when I manually register the dll using regasm, however, I need to deploy this control from a web page without having to manually register it. I tried creating a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010, it compiled fine yet I can not open the object in a webpage.

Here are the pertinent lines of code from my C# class:

```
namespace wmsSerialPorts
{
[Guid("55D31498-12A5-4FF0-942D-3B0BA449CA7B")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
      public interface iAxDevices
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        int OpenPort(string sComPort);
        [DispId(2)]
        int ClosePort();
        [DispId(3)]
        int SendCmd(string sCmd);
        [DispId(4)]
        string GetLastError();
        //[DispId(5)]
        //string ReadLine();
        [DispId(6)]
        string ReadWeight();
        [DispId(7)]
        Microsoft.JScript.ArrayObject GetJsPorts();
        [DispId(8)]
        void prtLabel(string sItemNum, string sQty, string sDesc, string sWoNum, string sBoxID, string sBoxIDBarCode, string sBoxIDorig);
        [DispId(9)]
        void prtLabelQC(string sItemNum, string sQty, string sDesc, string sWoNum, string sBoxID, string sBoxIDBarCode, string sBoxIDorig, string sNeedDate, string sRecOverride);
        [DispId(10)]
        void prtReset();
    }

[Guid("E59C5B7E-EF1F-4241-A9FD-191EF8FCC167")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("AxDevices")]
    public class AXDevices : wmsSerialPorts.SerialCom, iAxDevices, wmsSerialPorts.IObjectSafety
```

As I mentioned, if I use regasm wmsSerialPorts.dll, the object works great when called from JavaScript like this:

```
myAx = new ActiveXObject("AXDevices");
```

My Setup project contains a wmsSerialPorts.inf file:

```
[version]

signature="$CHICAGO$"

AdvancedINF=2.0

[Setup Hooks]

install=install

[install]

run=msiexec.exe /package """%EXTRACT_DIR%\ActiveXSetup.msi""" /qn
```

.... and an ActiveXBuild.ddf file:

```
.Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=cab

.Set CabinetNameTemplate=ActiveXSetup.cab

Debug\ActiveXSetup.msi

wmsSerialPorts.inf
```

My wmsSerialPorts.dll file is properly referenced as a detached asseembly and building the Setup Project created the ActiveXSetup.cab and ActiveXSetup.msi files as expected.

I then created this HTML page to load the object:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--    <object id="AXDevices" classid="clsid:E59C5B7E-EF1F-4241-A9FD-191EF8FCC167" codebase="https://10.0.2.53/BIDWMS/ActiveXSetup.cab">
    </object>-->
        <object id="AXDevices" classid="clsid:E59C5B7E-EF1F-4241-A9FD-191EF8FCC167" codebase="ActiveXSetup.cab">
    </object>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            var obj = document.AXDevices;
            if (obj) {
                alert(obj.SayHello());
            } else {
                alert("Object is not created!");
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("Error message is: " + ex.Description);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

... but when I run the page, it generates an error of "undefined" (from the catch(ex) block). Any ideas? Thanks in advance ....... Bob

Comment: Oops, pasted the wrong code. Here's the page: <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <object id="wmsSerialPorts" classid="clsid:E59C5B7E-EF1F-4241-A9FD-191EF8FCC167" codebase="ActiveXSetup.cab">

    </object>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            var obj = document.wmsSerialPorts;
            if (obj) {
                alert("Loaded");
            } else {
                alert("Object is not created!");
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("Error message is: " + ex.Description);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Your Codebase has to be a url, not just a filename. If your file is in C:\inetpub\myCabFiles\ActiveXSetup.cab, and your website is in C:\inetpub, then codebase should be something like

```
codebase="www.mywebsite.com\myCabFiles\ActiveXSetup.cab"
```